# Get text from the parent element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="form-cell">
    <label class="label">Company Name<span class="x">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-cell-value">
            <label class="readonly_label">
                <span>ABC PVT LIMITED</span>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="company" name="company" value="6">
 </div>
```

From the above code I know the id of input field, "company". By using this id I have to get the company name which is "ABC PVT LIMITED".

I tried this but it's not working:

```
value = $('#company').parent().find('.readonly_label').closest('span').text()
```

Comment: you added the jquery library?

Answer (score 2):

The `.closest()` function goes up the DOM hierarchy. Try using `.find()` or `.children()`:

```
value = $('#company').parent().find('.readonly_label').children('span').text()
```

Comment: @mohamed could you add your css with your html let me see how you use that html for how it looks

Answer (score 1):

Use a different selector with `find`:

```
value = $("#company").parent().find(".readonly_label > span").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `children` instead of `closest`.

```js
value = $('#company').parent().find('.readonly_label').children('span').text()
console.log(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-cell">
  <label class="label">Company Name<span class="x">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-cell-value">
    <label class="readonly_label"><span>ABC PVT LIMITED</span></label>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="company" name="company" value="6">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector

```
$('#company').siblings('.form-cell-value').find('.readonly_label > span').text();
```